# im having one textarea and button in html. when i click the button whatever content inside the textarea will be downloaded in the form of .DOCX file

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html

this is my  scenario

i'm having one text area and three buttons. one button is named as PDF
         another is named as doc and another one is  excel. if i'm entering any 
         data inside the text area and i have to download that content in these 
        three file  format. i have no idea how to do this . please help me to 
        resolve this

thanks in advance

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>file</title>
 </head>
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
 </script>
 <body id="target">
 <p> reason:</p>
 <div>
 <textarea id="content" rows="4" cols="70"></textarea>
 </div>
 <div id="editor"></div>
 <button  id="cmd">as pdf</button>
 <button  id="cmd1">as doc</button>
 <button  id="cmd2">as excel</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make a form, and treat these three buttons as submits. Then you can check, by post value, which "submit" was exactly clicked (for example, in php)

```
if($_POST['cmd']) { do_something(); }
if($_POST['cmd1']) { do_something_else(); }
if($_POST['cmd2']) { do_something_another(); }
```

And then get the textarea value as input, from that form.

Comment: but how to download it as .doc file?